# What is the ip xfrm tmpl and how is it different than an SA?

Tags: linux-networking, ipsec

The Linux `ip xfrm policy` command creates an IPsec policy, associating particular traffic with an SA.  It uses something called a "template" (`tmpl`), which, as far as I can tell, is just a means of identifying the SA.

Why does it call it a template? How is it different than an SA? And, why does it require repeating the src, dest, etc.; isn't the reqid enough to identify the SA?

Finally: Does the reqid have any significance other than as a local name for the SA? reqid doesn't seem to be part of the IPsec standard, and doesn't seem to go anywhere on the wire.  If it is a good means to identify the SA, why does the `xfrm policy` command use `tmpl` and other IDs (src, dest, proto, etc.)